# Render shared component from a Cell

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, partial-views, rails-cells

I'm using Cell and they are great, but I have some components in `app/views/shared/` that I would like to use inside a Cell.

Is that possible ?

Answer (score 3):

It was described on docs : )

> Sometimes you need to render a global partial from app/views within a
>   cell. For instance, the gmaps4rails helper depends on a global
>   partial. While this breaks encapsulation it’s still possible in cells
>   - just add the global view path.

```
class MapCell < Cell::Rails
  append_view_path "app/views"
```

( taken from: https://github.com/apotonick/cells )